# An Dictionary or KeyValuePair without KEY constrain

Tags: .net, generics, dictionary, key-value

I need to return a list of two values.
I tried Dictionary but the first parameter is the key and in my case it will repeat.
My list needs to return something like this:

Manager    - John Zambers

Developer  - Paul Myers

Developer  - John Zambers

Tester     - Mary Marie

etc...     - etc...

I dont want to create my own class to represent this list.
Dot.Net have a built in Type that represent it? Somethink like List()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`System.Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) class, e.g,:

```
List<Tuple<String, String>> people = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
people.Add(Tuple.Create("Manager", "John Zambers"));
// etc.
```

However, what's wrong with creating your own class? They can be almost self-documenting, especially in a simple case like this (e.g, it's obvious what's going to be in the `Name` field). For example:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Role { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Side note: I don't know your application domain or what all the possible roles/titles you have, but if you're doing any sort of processing based on this value it looks like a good place to use an [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead. E.g.,

```
public enum Roles
{
    Manager,
    Developer,
    Tester
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: Or List<DictionaryEntry> = new List<new DictionaryEntry("Manager", "John Zambers")>. Remember that Tuples are inmutable. So if you need to modify such entries after created Tuple won't do you any good :).

Comment: @Pedro `DictionaryEntry` seems inappropriate here -- while it would technically work, using `DictionaryEntry` carries some intrinsic meaning that the `Key` will be unique within the collection (which it clearly is not).

Comment: @Donut That wouldn't matter in this scenario because the uniqueness of the Key is implemented in the Dictionary class and not in the DictionaryEntry. Although I agree with you in that it may suggest that it actually is a Key.

Comment: @Pedro To me, the implicit suggestion that it actually is a `Key` is a pretty good reason to avoid it (even though `Dictionary` actually enforces the uniqueness).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> role_names = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> lst;

role_names.Add("Manager", lst = new List<string>());
lst.Add("John Zambers");

role_names.Add("Developer", lst = new List<string>());
lst.Add("Paul Myers");
lst.Add("John Zambers");

role_names.Add("Tester", lst = new List<string>());
lst.Add("Mary Marie");
```

Comment: assuming that you want a keyed lookup, this is probably the best option without writing a custom collection. Subtype this into a custom class and you can easily (via LINQ) provide a flat view of the all the values in the bag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Manager", "John"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Manager", "John"));
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Key);
```

You can also use something like `System.Web.UI.Pair` (which is not generic but pretty convenient sometimes).

But you should use it only if it really doesn't matter that first thing is a position and the second is a name. If you want to treat it as another one pair of something -- use KeyValuePair or Pair. But if it's a list of position and name pair, it might be a good idea to make a special type for it.

Answer (score 0):

.NET *does* have a class for this sort of thing, but you can't use it directly. It's `Lookup`, and is returned by the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx) method in LINQ.

If you can work out a way to use `ToLookup` on whatever source you've got for your data, it'll make your life a lot easier.

You could always use [my implementation of `Lookup`](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/Lookup.cs) from [Edulinq](http://edulinq.googlecode.com) if you wanted. Basically both implementations are immutable from outside the assembly itself, but you could change mine to be mutable if you wanted :)